# How to Add to an ObservableCollection<T> Item with LINQ Where() in Getter?

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm

I recently added a Disabled property to one of my domain entities. I have a `List<T>` of those entities in a view model. I just changed the getter to filter the list based on a UI setting to selectively show items that are disabled.

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomVariableGroup> CustomVariableGroups
{
    get
    {
        if (this.ShowDisabled) { return this._customVariableGroups; }

        return new ObservableCollection<CustomVariableGroup>(this._customVariableGroups.Where(x => x.Disabled == false));
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I now try to do this (in the same view model), the item doesn't get added to the collection.

```
this.CustomVariableGroups.Add(newGroup);
```

And I think I know why: The newGroup is being added to the new `ObservableCollection<T>`, not the backing field of _customVariableGroups.

If the LINQ Where() extension method was able to return `ObservableCollection<T>` (the type of the private backing field itself) instead of IEnumerable, I don't think I'd have this issue. As it stands now, since Where() returns `IEnumerable<T>`, I need to wrap that inside a new `ObservableCollection<T>`.

What is the right/best way for me to add a new item within the same view model? Do I need to add it directly to the private backing field? I don't want to do that because I don't want to have to remember not to use the property itself.

Comment: That's why I'm asking for help, bud. Instead of just calling it bad, can you suggest how to make it right?

Comment: Each time you call your property, a **new** observable collection is created....

Comment: At a higher level, where is the code `this.CustomVariableGroups.Add(newGroup);` located? You should create once the observable collection, and **sync** in some way the two lists. What is the type of CustomVariableGroups? Can't you simply create a collection source with filter over this property?

Comment: That code is in the same view model class, and it gets called when the user wants to add a new group. CustomVariableGroups is of type `ObservableCollection<CustomVariableGroup>` as shown in the code above.

Comment: @SteveB I think you stated the correct answer: create a collection source with filter over this property. The view model code shouldn't be altered based on what the view wants filtered. If it's a view concern, it should be handled in the view.

Comment: Based on that, the getter should return the entire `this._customVariableGroups` every time, and let the view filter what it doesn't want.

Comment: Ah, I just came across the reason I couldn't do this in the view. I have this comment next to the CollectionViewSource in the XAML: This works for the initial sort, but when members get added to the collection the sort doesn't get updated. That's because CollectionViewSource doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: use an icollectionview like in my answer - it supports filtering also when new items are added to the sourcecollection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of binding to your collection directly, you could bind to a **ICollectionView** and set a Filter in your Disabled property. no need to alter the source collection.

EDIT:

viewmodel:

```
 //this collection just init once - eg. in ctor, use add, remove, clear to alter
 public ObservableCollection<CustomVariableGroup> CustomVariableGroups {get; private set; }
 //create just once in ctor
 public ICollectionView MyView {get; private set;}

 //ctor
 this.CustomVariableGroups = new ObservableCollection<CustomVariableGroup>();
 this.MyView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.CustomVariableGroups);

 //in your disabled property set the filter
    public bool ShowDisabled
    {
        get { return _showDisabled; }
        set { 
            _showDisabled = value;

            if (_showDisabled)
                //show just disabled
                this.MyView.Filter = (item) =>
                                         {
                                             var myitem = (CustomVariableGroup) item;
                                             return myitem.Disabled;
                                         };
            else
            {
                //show all
                this.MyView.Filter = (item) => { return true; };
            }


            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ShowDisabled"); }
    }
```

xaml

```
    <CheckBox Content="ShowDisabled" IsChecked="{Binding ShowDisabled}"/>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyView}" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

this works in my testproject

Comment: Thank you! I'm not in a position to try this at the moment. I should be able to try it tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: How would the view model have a reference to CollectionViewSource?

Comment: ?? the code i posted is just viewmodel code, you just have to add the ICollectionView related stuff and all is working. i dont know what you mean with: "How would the view model have a reference to CollectionViewSource?" CollectionViewSource is from the System.Windows.Data namespace in PresentationFramework.dll. you just have to use it to create your ICollectionView from your ObservableCollection.

Comment: ah i think i get what you wanna ask. you dont need a CollectionViewSource in XAML (like you did in your answer) - and so of course no reference to this in your viewmodel. you just need the xaml i posted.

Comment: I finally got a chance to try this. It's not working because MyView ends up as null: `this.MyView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.CustomVariableGroups);`

Comment: My bad. I needed to put that code *after* loading the groups. Now it's not null, but it's not working just yet. Let me keep trying...

Comment: Got it! I had to tweak a few things (like don't use CollectionViewSource in XAML), but it's working now. This is excellent. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the right way to solve this is in the view, not the view model. This is a view concern only. I thought I'd post how I handled it, just in case this helps someone else.

First, the getter (view model) should just return the full list every time:

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomVariableGroup> CustomVariableGroups
{ get { return this._customVariableGroups; } }
```

Then, in the view, I added the filter event to my CollectionViewSource:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedGroups" Source="{Binding CustomVariableGroups}" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter">
```

And to get the list to refresh every time I clicked the Show Disabled checkbox:

```
Command="{Binding RefreshVariableGroupCommand}"
```

Then, in the code behind, I implemented the filter:

```
private void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    CustomVariableGroup customVariableGroup = e.Item as CustomVariableGroup;

    if (customVariableGroup == null) { return; }

    if ((bool)chkShowDisabled.IsChecked)
    {
        // Show everything
        e.Accepted = true;
        return;
    }

    // We are not showing disabled items, so set disabled items e.Accepted to false.
    if (customVariableGroup.Disabled == true)
    {
        e.Accepted = false;
        return;
    }

    e.Accepted = true;
}
```

The only part about this, that I don't like, is that I'm using MVVM and trying to avoid code-behind classes. But, it's better to have this than hack the view model.

Comment: you could do the same in your viewmodel, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would maintain your backing List and then raise the property changed for your ObservableCollection.

```
public ObservableCollection<CustomVariableGroup> CustomVariableGroups
{
    get
    {
        if (this.ShowDisabled) { return this._customVariableGroups; }

        return new ObservableCollection<CustomVariableGroup>  (this._customVariableGroups.Where(x => x.Disabled == false));
    }
}

// adds to the backing list but raises on property to rebuild and
// return the ObservableCollection
public void AddCustomVariableGroup(CustomVariableGroup newGroup)
{    
    this._customVariableGroups.Add(newGroup);
    OnPropertyChanged("CustomVariableGroups");
}

//Example invocation
AddCustomVariableGroup(newGroup);
```

Comment: Thanks, but now a developer has to remember not to use the property. I was trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a WinPhone app when showing filtered result. My solution was to bind to the "ShowDisabled" property change and on this event simply `Clear()` and readd stuff into the main Observable: CustomVariableGroups in this case. Something like this:

```
public bool ShowDisabled
{
    get
    {
        return showDisabled;
    }
    set
    {
        if (showDisabled!= value)
        {
            showDisabled = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ShowDisabled");
        }
    }
}
```

In the constructor add this: `this.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(MyViewModel_PropertyChanged);`

And in the Event Handler:

```
 void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.PropertyName == "ShowDisabled")
     {
         CustomVariableGroups.Clear();
         foreach (var cvg in AllVariableGroups.Where(x => !x.Disabled))
         {
             CustomVariableGroups.Add(cvg);
         }
     }
 }
```

The component bound to the `CustomVariableGroups` should update accordingly.

Disclaimer: of course there is a performance impact in this and you need to decide if it is negligible or not.

Comment: This would not work.  By clearing the collection before executing the Linq query, you are querying an empty collection.

Comment: whoops, sorry I was just copying and pasting from existing code and changing the names. Of course he will need to query from a backing property that always contains all the elements, or query before clearing the collection and then add. I edited the answer.

Comment: @Tallmaris Thanks, but this really seems more like a work-around than a proper approach. I'm hoping for something a little more simple/clean/elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like @Tallmaris, but instead of this in the `MyViewModel_PropertyChanged`:

```
     CustomVariableGroups.Clear();
     foreach (var cvg in CustomVariableGroups.Where(x => !x.Disabled))
     {
         CustomVariableGroups.Add(cvg);
     }
```

Do this:

```
     foreach(var cvg in CustomVariableGroups.Where( x => x.Disabled))
     {
         CustomVariableGroups.Remove(cvg);
     }
```

And if that doesn't work (depends if Enumerable.Where uses iterator blocks, I think), you can do this:

```
     foreach(var cvg in Custom VariableGroups.Where( x=> x.Disabled).ToList())
     {
         CustomVariableGroups.Remove(cvg);
     }
```